# AWS EKS enable basic auth

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is it possible to enable k8s basic auth in AWS EKS?

I need it to make Jenkins Kubernetes plugin work when Jenkins is deployed outside k8s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service account tokens. 
Read more about it here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can use service account tokens (as Bearer Tokens).

Service account bearer tokens are perfectly valid to use outside the cluster and can be used to create identities for long standing jobs that wish to talk to the Kubernetes API. To manually create a service account, simply use the `kubectl create serviceaccount (NAME)` command. This creates a service account in the current namespace and an associated secret.

```
kubectl create serviceaccount jenkins

serviceaccount "jenkins" created
```

Check an associated secret:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts jenkins -o yaml


apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  # ...
secrets:
- name: jenkins-token-1yvwg
```

The created secret holds the public CA of the API server and a signed JSON Web Token (JWT).

```
kubectl get secret jenkins-token-1yvwg -o yaml


apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: (APISERVER'S CA BASE64 ENCODED)
  namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
  token: (BEARER TOKEN BASE64 ENCODED)
kind: Secret
metadata:
  # ...
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

The signed JWT can be used as a bearer token to authenticate as the given service account.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control, install nginx-ingress and then tell it to enforce HTTP Basic authentication.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617